# using MCA in GIS for suitability analysis

Tags: algorithm, suitability-analysis

I have an essay about using MCD methods to solve suitability analysis.
I must write a scenario about fuzzy membership, WLC and AHP.

I feel that I’m confused about when and where to use each method. I read many papers that used the 3 methods in the same problem.
For example in landfill site selection,

1. first the fuzzy function used for data standardization (0,1).

Here I have a question: after determining the criteria (for example the distance from roads ) how to calculate the fuzzy function)?

2. Then WLC was used to give the different variables weights>

I need to know how weights are calculated?

3. Then AHP used to choose to best alternative.

In this case where Boolean can be used and how?
Is it possible to use one method only to solve such problem and get a good result?
Also I would like to know advantages and disadvantages of each method.